# How can I get expire date from jwt token in go?

Tags: go, jwt

I have a jwt token and I am able to see the decoded token in `https://jwt.io/` website. It doesn't require me to setup any secret or claims. so I am looking for a way to decode the token to get expire date without providing any secret.

I am using the library `gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2/jwt` and below is my code:

```
token, err := jwt.ParseSigned(jwtToken)
```

the returned value `token` has a Header field which includes KeyId, Algorithm but it doesn't give me expire date.

I have searched on this topic and people say using `github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/v2/validator` library but it requires setting up key/secret. Is secret required for parsing the expire date from the token. How does the website `https://jwt.io/` knows the expire date?

Comment: Expires is part of the claims. Use [UnsafeClaimsWithoutVerification](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2/jwt#JSONWebToken.UnsafeClaimsWithoutVerification) to parse them. As the name suggests, you cannot trust the value unless you verify the signature. See the examples for [JSONWebToken.Claims](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2/jwt#JSONWebToken.Claims) for usage.

Comment: *the returned value token has a Header field* - what else does it contain? Please post the full result. A JWT consists of header, payload and signature. Header and payload are just Base64Url encoded and you yound need a key to read them. The expiration is part of the payload (exp claim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sample JWT token from jwt.io, [this code](https://go.dev/play/p/JpF0pqoy-wl) parses and retrieves the claims without verifying the signature:

```
func main() {
    raw := "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"

    t, err := jwt.ParseSigned(raw)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var claims map[string]any
    if err := t.UnsafeClaimsWithoutVerification(&claims); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(claims)
}
```

The expiration should appear as one of the fields in the `claims` map in this example. To retrieve it, use `exp, ok := claims["expire"]` (depending on the exact name).

Comment: yes it works. I wonder why we need secret to decode the token if we can do that without any credential?

Comment: The secret is required to verify that the token can be trusted. Otherwise, anybody can manipulate the data inside it since it's basically plain text. So you can always see the data, but to trust it you have to run verify it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Peter answer, the expires is in the **Claims** struct, if you are using jose library, maybe this step can help:

```
//create struct jwt claim, it usually for encode and decode token
type JWTClaim struct {
   *jwt.Claims
}
//decode the jwt token
parsedJwt, err := jwt.ParseSigned(rawToken)
result := JWTClaim{}
err := parsedJwt.Claims(key, &result)
expiryAt := result.ExpiresAt
mytime := time.Unix(expiryAt, 0)
fmt.Println(mytime)
```

I'm still not sure about the answer, but you can try it. jwt package that I'm using is golang-jwt, haven't try go-jose yet.